# obtainStyledAttributes() confusion, defStyleRes

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles

I have a custom view, in a library. I want the library consumer to be able to define attrs for my view, either in a style or on view's XML, and also to have defaults, defined in my library used if neither of those exist.

If I do this:

```
getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, 0, 0);
```

I correctly get the attrs from the consumer's style. If I do this,

```
getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, 0, R.style.MyStyle);
```

Where `MyStyle` is defined **in my library**, I get the values from `MyStyle` regardless of whether the consumer has defined the attrs or not; `MyStyle` always overrides values from consumer.

What's the right pattern to define default style attrs in a library? I realize I could simply get the values from `getResources()...` inside my view.

EDIT:
This post helped:
https://blog.danlew.net/2016/07/19/a-deep-dive-into-android-view-constructors/

Specifically,

> Here's their order of precedence, from highest to lowest:
>
> 1. Any value defined in the AttributeSet.
> 2. The style resource defined in the AttributeSet (i.e. style=@style/blah).
> 3. The default style attribute specified by defStyleAttr.
> 4. The default style resource specified by defStyleResource (if there was no defStyleAttr).
> 5. Values in the theme.

So in my case, the consumer defined the attrs in their theme, which is absolute lowest priority. That explains why it's working as such, but I still don't understand what is the right pattern.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I'm trying to help but I didn't really get what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I'm asking what is the correct pattern for a library to define default style attrs to be used if the consumer of the lib does not defined them.

Comment: what's the problem with this? getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, 0, R.style.MyStyle);

Comment: I used getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes in my projects